# What's the correct American translation for the family name "Würker"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, person-names

I'm interested to know the correct American English form of Würker.

Any general background information on this name's roots would also probably prove insightful as well.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Correct according to which criterion?

Comment: Generally it should look and particularly "sound" American (so without the umlaut), and preferably have a similar root or meaning.

Comment: Thanks for that :) I'm also curious to know if "Worker" is an established American transliteration, in common use?

Comment: This may probably better be answered at http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, okay! [I've asked there - thanks! :)](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5517/how-much-is-worker-an-established-american-transliteration-of-the-german-w%C3%BCrk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally family names should not be translated, as they are genuine names that stand as they are. However in case we must it depends whether we wanted to transtlate the meaning (Metzger > *Butcher*, Bäcker > *Baker*, Müller > *Miller*), or if we wanted to find a name that is being pronounced the same.

The example name *[Würker](http://www.heraldrysinstitute.com/cognomi/W%C3%BCrker/Germany/idc/752400/lang/de/)* offers both, as it likely derives from the Middle High German verb *würken*, which today became *wirken* in modern German and *work* in English.

Hence an etymologically correct transfer would be **Worker**, which would also be pronounced similarly in both, English and German.

Comment: Danke für die Informationen, das war wirklich aufschlussreich! :D